# Going from string to stringstream to vector<int>

Tags: c++, string, vector, stringstream

I've this sample program of a step that I want to implement on my application. I want to push_back the int elements on the string separately, into a vector. How can I?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string line = "1 2 3 4 5"; //includes spaces
    stringstream lineStream(line);


    vector<int> numbers; // how do I push_back the numbers (separately) here?
    // in this example I know the size of my string but in my application I won't


    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
int num;
while (lineStream >> num) numbers.push_back(num);
```

Answer (score 35):

This is a classic example of `std::back_inserter`.

```
copy(istream_iterator<int>(lineStream), istream_iterator<int>(),
     back_inserter(numbers));
```

You can create the vector right from the start on, if you wish

```
vector<int> numbers((istream_iterator<int>(lineStream)), 
                    istream_iterator<int>());
```

Remember to put parentheses around the first argument. The compiler thinks it's a function declaration otherwise. If you use the vector for just getting iterators for the numbers, you can use the istream iterators directly:

```
istream_iterator<int> begin(lineStream), end;
while(begin != end) cout << *begin++ << " ";
```

Comment: This is a perfect example, imho, of whats wrong with C++. In virtually every other language, this would be a split on ' ', followed by something like .toInt() for each element. Instead, we have an immensely complicated collection of templatized algorithms being applied.

Comment: I hear what you're saying dicroce.  OTOH, this more complicated approach is faster, since you avoid creating a temporary array or list of strings, and also more powerful -- much the same code could be used to copy any sort of "range of values" (represented by a pair of iterators) into a vector.

Comment: C++11: `vector<int> numbers(istream_iterator<int>(lineStream), {});`

Comment: @KerrekSB yours is the first non-theoretic example I have seen for passing an initializer list to a deduced template parameter. Nice