# get list of numbers from stdin and tokenize them

Tags: c++, tokenize, stringstream

How would I get a list of numbers from the user and then tokenize them.

This is what I have but it doesn't get anything except for the first number:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string line = "";
    cin >> line;

    stringstream lineStream(line);

    int i;
    vector<int> values;

    while (lineStream >> i)
        values.push_back(i);

    for(int i=0; i<values.size(); i++)
        cout << values[i] << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Related Posts:
[C++, Going from string to stringstream to vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455483/c-going-from-string-to-stringstream-to-vectorint)
[Int Tokenizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141741/int-tokenizer)

Comment: Type multiple numbers on one line separated by space followed by return and it will get all of them. The problem is you are only reading the first line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe cin >> breaks on whitespace, which means you're only getting the first number entered.

try:

```
getline(cin, line);
```

Comment: not if you put it in a loop:  while(std::cin >> i) { /* Do STUFF */ }

Comment: why loop, when you can do it in one call?

Answer (score 5):

Here is probably the easiest way to read values from `cin` into a container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values;
    std::copy(
        std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 
        std::istream_iterator<int>(),
        std::back_inserter(values));

    // For symmetry with the question copy back to std::cout
    std::copy(
        values.begin(),
        values.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,"\n"));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Donnie mentioned cin breaks on whitespace, so do overcome this we can use a 'getline()', the following example works nicely:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string line = "";
    ::getline(std::cin,line,'\n');

    std::stringstream lineStream(line);

    int i;
    std::vector<int> values;

    while (lineStream >> i)
        values.push_back(i);

    for(int i=0; i<values.size(); i++)
        cout << values[i] << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on top of main

```
string line = "";
getline (cin, line );
stringstream lineStream(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, and is the string version of getline, no the istream one.

Answer (score 0):

OK: Pavel Minaev has the best answer.
But all the people mentioning that cin breaks on white space.
That is a good thing (because it also ignores white space);

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int i;
    vector<int> values;

    // prefer to use std::copy() but this works.
    while (std::cin >> i)
    {
        values.push_back(i);
    }

    // prefer to use std::copy but this works.
    for(vector<int>::const_iterator loop = values.begin();loop != values.end();++loop)
    {
        cout << *loop << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```